# Is there a way to tell Xcode to default to multiline method calls when formatting code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a way to tell Xcode to default to multiline method calls when it is autocompleting a method?  Failing that, is there a way for Ctrl-I to automatically format long method calls to wrap?  Basically I want this:

[image]

Comment: i have read about it on [scoop-it](http://www.scoop.it/t/ios-os-x-development?page=2) some times before. here is link [XAlign](https://github.com/qfish/XAlign)